# Font won't load into iOS application (can't see it in Xcode)

Tags: ios, fonts, interface-builder

I've purchased a Font (**UniversLTStd**) and included the `.ttf` file in my application.

I can see the font name in my `Info.plist` file.

When I click on a UILabel in Interface Builder and attempt to select this font, it's not there. Am I missing something?

Xcode: Version 7.1

Comment: do add files and select the .ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see font enlisted from InterfaceBuilder you should install it in you operation system.

Open ttf file with Fonts app and click install. Basically, just double click it - it will use Fonts.app as default to open in. In the right-lower corner you'll find, what you need

Comment: Thank you! I can't seem to install this font though. When I drag the files into Font Book, it doesn't appear. :

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the Font file itself. The naming is corrupted so it won't intsall

Comment: Too bad. In that case, sorry, but I have no idea how to help you. Maybe try to set font from code in run time?

Comment: I get `NULL` when I try to set the font at runtime

Comment: I guess problem is with ttf file itself then. What error do you get, trying to install it?

Comment: So I've fixed this problem by using the `otf` file instead. But your answer was correct (once I'd fixed the font file)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Could you please explain, what have you done? Used some kind of converter? Or just get `off` file from where you get the original `ttf` ?